# How to detect if an array has been completely looped through

Tags: swift, loops, uicollectionview, for-in-loop

I have using a for-in loop to retrieve keys from an array of dictionaries, and after all the keys have been appended to an array, I want to reload a collection view. How can I detect if all the keys have been looped through and retrieved. I could reload the collection view within the for-in loop except that would result in multiple unnecessary reloads which I believe are slowing down my application.

```
for (key, _) in dictionaries {
                let userId = key
                self.userIds.append(userId)
            }
```

Comment: I don't understand the problem - why can't you call the reload outside the for loop (i.e. after the closing brace)?

Answer (score 0):

By definition, the for loop will loop through all the keys. You don't have to check that. Just call the reload method after the end braces.

However, This is not a correct way of getting keys of a dictionary. Try

```
userIds = Array(dictionaries.keys)
collectionView.reload()
```